# Notable to read .xls format file using roo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Roo gem not working with xls format

Using Rails 4.2

```
require 'roo'
require 'spreadsheet'
class TextMig
 file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/Article.xls"

 def self.data_import
     ex = Roo::Excel.new(file_path)
     puts "434444#{ex}"
     ex.default_sheet = ex.sheets[1]
       puts ex
       HText.delete_all
       3.upto(50) do |line|
          a1 =  ex.cell(line, 'B')
          a2 =  ex.cell(line, 'C')
          a3 =  ex.cell(line, 'D')
          a4 =  ex.cell(line, 'E')
          HText.create(:model_name => a1,:field_name => a2,:identifier => a3,:h_text=>a4)
       end
   end
 end
```

Sometime `Roo::Excel.new(file_path)` is getting nil value.

The main problem is values not reading.

Comment: `Roo` never claimed it can handle old binary `xls` format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an app that loads .xls files without problems.

What if you try:

```
Roo::Excel.new(file_path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore) ?
```